# Delete rows from array & database

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I develop an application in which I need to delete the rows from array as well as database..?In **cellForRowAtIndexPath** I write like **cell.textLabel.Text=[myarray.objectAtIndexPath.row];** I Want to delete that row from database and array also.In Editing method I write the code like

```
MoneyAppDelegate *mydelegate=(MoneyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        database *objdata=[[database alloc]init];
        [app deleteCategory:objdata];        
        [self.mytableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

But it not work. In deletecategory method I have code like

```
-(void)deleteCategory:(database *)databaseObj
{
[databaseObj deleteCategory];
 [myarray removeObject:databaseObj];
}
```

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

MoneyAppDelegate *app = (MoneyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

  cell.textLabel.text = [app.myarray4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;}
```

deletecategory is the method to delete the record from Database.nothing else.
How can i delete that selected row from database I know its very simple but yet I confused..thnanx in advance:)

Comment: thnx for editing i remind it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this-

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self delBtnPressed:indexPath.row];
}
```

//here you place your code-

```
-(void)delBtnPressed:(int)sender
 {  
NSString *titleStr=@"";
    NSString *table=@"";
NSString *attribute=@"";

sqlite3 *database;

if(![titleStr isEqualToString:@""])
{
    //-------------------------------deletion-------------------------  

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {

        NSString *  sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from %@ where %@='%@' ",table,attribute,titleStr];

        if (sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlStatement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NULL, NULL, NULL)  == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            [yourArr removeAllObjects];
            [self fetchAgain]; //here you need to fetch all records from DB and fill the yourArr again.
            [tblView reloadData];

        }
        sqlite3_close(database);

    }

}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Error while deleting please try again");
}

}
```

Comment: thnx for repl but my code is wrk perfectly..but it just delete from simulator not from database @Naina

Comment: I didn't get your problem of working in simulator but not on device..you must be doing something wrong somewhere..you can debug your problem with the help of **SMART BREAKPOINTS** in XCODE. or if you are using sqlite than you can try with my simple code.

Comment: R u in Gmail Or any other Acoount?can we discuss there ?@Naina

Comment: u r right m talikng about the sqlite database..i need to delete the record from it..

Answer (score 0):

Check this line..

```
database *objdata=[[database alloc]init];
[app deleteCategory:objdata];
```

In the first line you are just creating an object for "`database`" as "`objdata`" and alloc it.In this place there will be nothing in "`objdata`". So when you pass this to `deleteCategory`: method, there is nothing will get deleted in database. So here is a problem.

Try this:

```
 database *objdata=[[database alloc]init];
 objdata = [myarray.objectAtIndexPath.row];
[app deleteCategory:objdata];
```

Comment: it gives error like -[__NSCFString deleteCategory]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a5fe20
 in delegate method @R.A

Comment: objdata = [myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; try like this

Comment: paste your cellForRowAtindexPath: method in your question

Comment: objdata = [app.myarray4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; did you try like this??

Comment: That's Fine. Good. I didn't know that you haven't got the indexPath.row value. Anyway :-)